# Show for $n>3$ satisfying this identity, that $n$ is not prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

While programming with prime numbers, I noticed the pattern that for $n>3$ satisfying this identity, then $n$ is **not** prime. Is that true?

$$
\frac {(n-1)(n-2)}2 \equiv 1 \pmod{3}
$$

Also, it seems for any potential prime $n$, the chance of that identity being true is $1/3$.

**EDIT**

The origin of that identity was derived from Picks Theorem

$A=I + \frac{B}{2}-1$

Define $x+y=n$ with area $A = n^2/2$ and boundary $B=3n$

$I = \frac{n^2}{2} - \frac{3n}{2}+1 = \frac{n^2-3n}{2}+1 = \frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2}$

Notice the $gcd(I,B)$ is $1$ (not prime) or $3$ (possibly prime).

Comment: If $(n-1)(n-2)/2 \equiv 1 \bmod 3$ then $n\equiv 0 \bmod 3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(n-1)(n-2)\equiv2\pmod3$
$n^2-3n+2\equiv2\pmod3$
$n^2\equiv0\pmod3$
$n\equiv0\pmod3$

Comment: I'm not familiar with mod maths. Did you skip any steps? Is there a good reference to lookup on howto perform mod maths? Thanks!

Comment: just multiply both sides by 2. equate 3n to 0.  "mod maths" is usually called "modular arithmetic". can search onlne for "modular arithmetic".